# How to disable Buffer in OpenCV Camera?

Tags: node.js, opencv, camera, buffer

I have this situation where I use OpenCV to detect faces in front of the camera and do some ML on those faces. The issue that I have is that once I do all the processing, and go to grab the next frame I get the past, not the present. Meaning, I'll read whats inside the buffer, and not what is actually in front of the camera. Since I don't care which faces came in front of the camera while processing, I care what is now in front of the camera.

I did try to set the buffer size to `1`, and that did help quite a lot, but I still will get at least 3 buffer reads. Setting the FPS to 1, also dose not help remove this situation 100%. Bellow is the flow that I have.

```
let cv = require('opencv4nodejs');

let camera = new cv.VideoCapture(camera_port);

camera.set(cv.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1);
camera.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS, 2);
camera.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES , 1);

function loop()
{
    //
    //  <>> Grab one frame from the Camera buffer.
    //
    let rgb_mat = camera.read();

    //  Do to gray scale

    //  Do face detection

    //  Crop the image

    //  Do some ML stuff

    //  Do whats needs to be done after the results are in.

    //
    //  <>> Release data from memory
    //
    rgb_mat.release();

    //
    //  <>> Restart the loop
    //
    loop();
}
```

## My question is:

Is it possible to remove the buffer all-together? And if so, how. If not, a `why` would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using the async read method and process only the frame you are interested in discard others.

Answer (score 21):

Whether `CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE` is supported appears quite operating system and backend-specific.  E.g., the [2.4 docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get) state it is "only supported by DC1394 [Firewire] v 2.x backend currently," and for backend V4L, according to the [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp#L164), support was added only on 9 Mar 2018.

The easiest non-brittle way to disable the buffer is using a separate thread; for details, see my comments under Piotr Kurowski's answer.  Here Python code that uses a separate thread to implement a bufferless VideoCapture:  (I did not have a opencv4nodejs environment.)

```py
import cv2, Queue, threading, time

# bufferless VideoCapture
class VideoCapture:

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
    self.q = Queue.Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target=self._reader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

  # read frames as soon as they are available, keeping only most recent one
  def _reader(self):
    while True:
      ret, frame = self.cap.read()
      if not ret:
        break
      if not self.q.empty():
        try:
          self.q.get_nowait()   # discard previous (unprocessed) frame
        except Queue.Empty:
          pass
      self.q.put(frame)

  def read(self):
    return self.q.get()

cap = VideoCapture(0)
while True:
  frame = cap.read()
  time.sleep(.5)   # simulate long processing
  cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
  if chr(cv2.waitKey(1)&255) == 'q':
    break
```

The frame reader thread is encapsulated inside the custom `VideoCapture` class, and communication with the main thread is via a queue.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30032945/1628638) suggests using `cap.grab()` in a reader thread, but the docs do not guarantee that `grab()` clears the buffer, so this may work in some cases but not in others.

Comment: Nice clean solution but standard is queue.Queue() though ?

Comment: This one still has some problems. It reads 1 frame late

Answer (score 2):

I set cap value after reading each frame to None and my problem solved in this way:

```
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

if __name__ == '__main__':
while True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('A', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    print('sleep!')
    QThread.sleep(5)
    print('wake up!')
    cap = None
```

Comment: So, you are basically deleting the whole class, and force it to recreate at each loop, thus having to load a new frame?

Comment: With this a new frame will load not a buffered frame.@DavidGatti

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but in C++. I didn't find proper solution in OpenCV but I found a workaround. This buffer accumulates a constant number of images, say n frames. So You can read n frames without analysis and read frame once more. That last frame will be live image from camera. Something like:

```
buffer_size = n;

for n+1
{
  // read frames to mat variable
}
// Do something on Mat with live image
```

Comment: So, the idea would be: find out the last frame in the buffer, use if if there is any, ask the camera for more if no frame was returned? Yes, No, Maybe? :)

Comment: The catch is you typically do not know how many frames to read at a certain point in time.  To fix this, one could, e.g., time how long the `cap.read()` takes, and assume it was from the buffer if it was fast.  But this does not work well, e.g., if the frame processing takes just about the time between frames, in which case one would assume the frame read right after processing was from the buffer and end up dropping every other frame.

Comment: You have to check how many frames are in buffer. In my case it was always 5, but it isn't an const number. In my example You should read 5+1 frames to be sure that last frame will be actual.

Comment: Assuming there are always a certain number of frames in the buffer leads to brittle code: the constant needs to be adjusted, e.g., if the analysis code is changed, if the time the analysis takes changes for other reasons (library change, machine change, etc.), or if the frame rate changes (due to lighting change, different camera, etc.).

Comment: So, how dose one check how many frames are in the buffer with OpenCV? Is there a function that will tell you that?

Comment: @DavidGatti, there is no such function.