# Using opencv python on a jetson Nano, how to reduce capture latency with high resolution camera?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am using a Jetson Nano to capture high resolution image (21MP, 5344x4012@9FPS, Grayscale, IMX230) and finding aruco markers in them. Running the `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers` function takes about 2 seconds with current aruco parameters. When testing my system, I was hoping to get a maximum latency of about 2 seconds. However, every frames that are executed by the program are always 15 seconds late. The latency is constant and won't change during program execution.

My first instinct was that I was using the oldest image from a buffer and I tried remedy this problem with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69141497/16871420). It's basically making a new thread that empties the camera buffer. I modified it a bit so the thread is running indefinitely and the `self.cap.read()` function is prioritized with `runFlag` :

```
# This interface code is based on this arducam repository:
# https://github.com/ArduCAM/MIPI_Camera/tree/master/Jetson/Jetvariety/example

from utils import ArducamUtils
import time
import cv2
import threading

# bufferless VideoCapture from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69141497
class VideoCapture:
  def __init__(self):
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
    
    # create arducam utilities
    self.arducam_utils = ArducamUtils(0)
  
    # turn off RGB conversion
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)

    # set pixel format
    fourcc_cap = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'Y16 ') # Grayscale
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC,fourcc_cap) 
    
    # set height and width for max resolution
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 5344)
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 4012)

    # set max buffer size to 1 frame to limit latency
    print(self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1))
    
    print("[INFO] " + str(self.arducam_utils.get_pixfmt_cfg()))

    # start thread to empty the camera buffer
    self.runFlag = True
    self.t = threading.Thread(target=self._reader)
    self.t.daemon = True
    self.t.start()

  # grab frames as soon as they are available
  def _reader(self):
    while True:
      time.sleep(1.0/9.0)
      if self.runFlag:
        ret = self.cap.grab()
        print("[INFO] Grabbing...")

  # retrieve latest frame
  def read(self):
    self.runFlag = False
    ret, frame = self.cap.read()
    self.runFlag = True
    return frame

  def display(self):
    while True:
      frame = self.read()
      
      w = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
      h = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
      frame = frame.reshape(int(h), int(w))

      frame = self.arducam_utils.convertGrayScale(frame)
      
      frame = resize(frame, 1280.0)
      # display
      cv2.imshow("Arducam", frame)
      ret = cv2.waitKey(1)
      # press 'q' to exit.
      if ret == ord('q'):
        break

  def getFrame(self):
    frame = self.read()
    
    w = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    h = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    frame = frame.reshape(int(h), int(w))
    
    frame = self.arducam_utils.convertGrayScale(frame)

    print('[INFO] New Frame.')
    return frame

def resize(frame, dst_width):
  width = frame.shape[1]
  height = frame.shape[0]
  scale = dst_width * 1.0 / width
  return cv2.resize(frame, (int(scale * width), int(scale * height)))
```

With this hack/fix, I reduced the latency to about 8 seconds. How can I get 2 seconds latency?

Comment: run frame capture in a free-running thread. store the latest frame there. in the aruco processing thread, use whatever frame is currently stored there.

Comment: two seconds? aruco really needs a pyramid scheme for its edge extraction phase.

Comment: the "thread" approach you linked is garbage. they merely differentiate between grab and retrieve. the thread has to do all the reading, and then save the frame in some variable. you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755738/2602877

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks! I tried to code you linked and it works very well. Kind of new to stackoverflow but should I post the answer to my own question?

Comment: in general, you can post an answer on your own question. in this instance, if *that question* there has an answer that exactly solves the issue here, this question should be marked as a duplicate. the below comment is auto-generated by the site from such a flag. this type of linkage is supposed to help search engines make the connection.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the question was marked as duplicate, thanks again.